# ggplotly in R : change data label size

Tags: r, plotly, ggplotly

I have to convert a `ggplot` to a `plotly`. Naturally, the easiest way to do so seems to be using `ggploty`, but the font size change. No problem to get back to the good size for axis labels and title, but I cannot figure how to do this for data labels? Any ideas? I do prefer to keep the `ggplot` and wrap it with `ggplotly` (many other plots as well).

I tried the font from layout with no success:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

tbl <- data.frame(
  indicateur = c("freq1", "freq2", "freq3" ),
  valeur = c(44, 78, 84)
)

ggplotly(
  ggplot(tbl) +
    geom_bar(aes(x = indicateur, y = valeur), stat = 'identity', fill = rgb(31, 119, 180, maxColorValue = 255)) +
    geom_text(aes(x = indicateur, y = valeur, label = valeur), vjust = -0.5) + 
    ylim(0, max(tbl$valeur)*1.1) +
    labs(x = "", y = "", title = "simple counting") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(
      axis.line = element_blank(), 
      panel.border = element_blank(),
      plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)
    )
  ) %>%
  layout(
    showlegend = FALSE, 
    textfont = list(size = 5), 
    titlefont = list(size = 12),
    xaxis = list(tickfont = list(size = 9))
  )
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just passing `size` into `geom_text`? In addition, I do not believe all the layout adjustments are necessary. See the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

tbl <- data.frame(
  indicateur = c("freq1", "freq2", "freq3" ),
  valeur = c(44, 78, 84)
)

p_size_5 <- ggplot(tbl, aes(x = indicateur, y = valeur, label = valeur)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = rgb(31, 119, 180, maxColorValue = 255)) +
  geom_text(vjust = -0.5, size = 5) +
  labs(
    title = "simple counting (text 5)",
    x = NULL, y = NULL
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.line = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)
  )

ggplotly(p_size_5)
```

[image: size 5]

```
p_size_2 <- ggplot(tbl, aes(x = indicateur, y = valeur, label = valeur)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = rgb(31, 119, 180, maxColorValue = 255)) +
  geom_text(vjust = -0.5, size = 2) +
  labs(
    title = "simple counting (text 2)",
    x = NULL, y = NULL
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.line = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)
  )

ggplotly(p_size_2)
```

[image: size 2]

Comment: Thanks! I had completely forgotton that it's possible to pass some values to plotly directly from within ggplot! Well, I need those extra layout options formy actual axis labels are long and for them to be legible, I need a smaller font size.